# how to set slots in rasa stories. can you explain me

Tags: rasa-core

How to set slots in rasa stories

Comment: I like the question, don't understand why it has been marked down, especially when no one could be bothered to say why they marked it down. It's lazy, rude and says more about the people doing it than it does about your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for taking so long to answer your question! In addition to Stack Overflow, another great place to ask questions is the Rasa Community Forum, which you can find [here](https://forum.rasa.com/).

For Rasa stories, you can initially set slots in your domain file like this:

```
slots:
  name:
    type: text
    initial_value: "human"
```

During a conversation, there are a few different ways to set slots:

1. Slots Set from NLU: If your NLU model picks up an entity, and your domain contains a slot with the same name, the slot will be set automatically. In this case, you don’t have to include the - slot{} part in the story, because it is automatically picked up.
2. Slots Set By Clicking Button: You can use buttons as a shortcut. Rasa Core will send messages starting with a / to the RegexInterpreter, which expects NLU input in the same format as in story files like this:

```
utter_ask_color:
- text: "what color would you like?"
  buttons:
  - title: "blue"
    payload: '/choose{"color": "blue"}'
  - title: "red"
    payload: '/choose{"color": "red"}'
```

3. Slots Set by Actions: You can set slots by returning events in custom actions. In this case, your stories need to include the slots. Refer to the docs below to see an example of how this is done.

Rasa is always evolving, so make sure to check out the Rasa Docs to get the most up to date information about how to set slots, which you can find [here](http://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/).

Comment: @thirupathinethaJadi Could you please tick the answer if this solved your problem?

Comment: these are still the only ways to do it. There is no way within stories to do it yet.

Comment: I wanna ask if the user does not click on any button and writing something else, how can I know to fill this slot? espcially, in case if I used quick replies button that will hide if the user enter any thing !!!